# PDDocument.load() function taking more time to load file

Tags: java, spring, pdf, pdfbox

I am using **pdfbox** library for loading any pdf file

the code snippet is as below

`PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(pdfFile)`

This code is working for most of the case
but for some of the files (even for small files like 20mb), this function takes more than 5 minutes to laod the file.

I had tried uploading a 60 mb file this function is not taking that much time but in some cases, it takes a longer time.

Can anyone tell me in what kind of content it will take time?

And what should we do for that kind of content?

Comment: You could try profiling/sampling while your application is loading different pdf files and then compare the collected data to find any differences.

Comment: What version are you using? Can you share the file? And how is this related to spring?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I can not share the file for security reasons. I am using version 2.0.24 of pdfbox.

Comment: The current version is 2.0.26. Also try to run PDFDebugger in the latest 3.0 alpha and look at the status line https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/pdfbox/3.0.0-alpha3/debugger-app-3.0.0-alpha3.jar